# Generic map print function

Tags: java, generics

I have a function prints `Map` objects,

```
public static void printMap(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {          
        System.out.println( entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue() );
    }
}
```

Now, I want my function to work with `Map<String, Integer>` type of maps too. How to do it? I always wanted to use generics, hope to have a good start with this question.

Answer (score 8):

You can write generic methods as in below code:

```
public static <K, V> void printMap(Map<K, V> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {          
         System.out.println( entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue() );
    }
}
```

**Suggested Read:**

- [Angelika Langer - Generic Methods](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html)

---

As pointed out by @JBNizet in comments, you can also write the method using *wildcards* `(?)` instead of type parameters as below:

```
public static void printMap(Map<?, ?> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {          
         System.out.println( entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue() );
    }
}
```

Comment: @PrasadKharkar. I would suggest you to go through the linked site. That is an awesome reading on generics.

Comment: sure :) I will go through it

Comment: Why make this method generic? Why not simply make it take a Map<?, ?> as argument?

Comment: @JBNizet. Oh! right, that will be better. Will edit my answer. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with wildcard `Map<? extends Object, Integer>`. This line means that you can have anything that extends Object class. So it can be `String`, `Integer`, `UserDefinedObject`. Anything.

Answer (score 1):

Doubt you need the method really - Use `toString()` of Map instance, that's it.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question - it will have different behavior. Anyway the OP's trying to learn generics here.